# facebook localization of hosted objects

Tags: facebook, localization, facebook-opengraph

[This doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/) states that one can localize the hosted object by getting the objects id and doing POST to that object with localized values in params. 
But following that I do not get the described result. Instead new values replace old values and that's it.

The flow is like this:

1. Request apptoken for my app.
2. Using that token POST  to `facebookgraphroot/app/objects/%objectType%` with json string describing object in params. that perfectly creates my object and returns me the objects id.
3. using above token and acquired objects id POST to `facebookgraphroot/%ObjectId%` with json string representing localized object. And this replaces the previous one.

The json strings representing objects in both cases have "locale" attr and the value of this attr is different for 2-d and 3-d step. Those values are picked up from facebook provided xml doc.

So whats wrong with all of this?

Answer (score 0):

[It is actually a known bug that has been reported](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/697517653622499/) to the Facebook Engineering Team. Last updated 2 days ago (from the time I am writing this).

Let's hope that they FIX this quickly!