# Open Graph Localization example does not work

Tags: facebook, bash, localization, facebook-opengraph

I'm following Facebook's localization guide for [Hosted Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/#HostedObjects)

My bash script is:

```
OBJECTID=$(curl -X POST \
-F 'object={"locale":"es_ES",
            "title":"mi objeto",
            "description":"mi descripción", 
            "data": { "obj_extra":"mi información" } }' \
"https://graph.facebook.com/$APPID/objects/$APPNAMESPACE:$OBJTYPE?access_token=$APPID|$APPSECRET")

OBJECTID=${OBJECTID//[!0-9]/}
echo ID = $OBJECTID

curl -X POST \
-F 'object={"locale":"en_US",
            "title":"my english object",
            "description":"my english description"}' \
"https://graph.facebook.com/$OBJECTID?access_token=$APPID|$APPSECRET"

echo Spanish:
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/$OBJECTID?access_token=$APPID|$APPSECRET&locale=es_ES"

echo English:
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/$OBJECTID?access_token=$APPID|$APPSECRET&locale=en_US"
```

And my output is:

```
ID = 270580863098812
{"type":"barnstormerdev:mobile_item","title":"my english object","locale":{"locale":"en_us"},"description":"my english description","updated_time":"2014-02-28T21:12:45+0000","id":"270580863098812","application":{"id":"239752792848708","name":"BarnStormerDev","url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/apps\/application.php?id=239752792848708"}}
Spanish:
{"id":"270580863098812","type":"barnstormerdev:mobile_item","title":"my english object","locale":{"locale":"en_us"},"description":"my english description","updated_time":"2014-02-28T21:12:45+0000","created_time":"2014-02-28T21:12:45+0000","application":{"id":"239752792848708","name":"BarnStormerDev","url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/apps\/application.php?id=239752792848708"},"is_scraped":false}
English:
{"id":"270580863098812","type":"barnstormerdev:mobile_item","title":"my english object","locale":{"locale":"en_us"},"description":"my english description","updated_time":"2014-02-28T21:12:45+0000","created_time":"2014-02-28T21:12:45+0000","application":{"id":"239752792848708","name":"BarnStormerDev","url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/apps\/application.php?id=239752792848708"},"is_scraped":false}
```

Which is not correct since both are english. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to confirm your findings and report what I tested:

**a)** I tried various *locale* values, like *uppercase* vs *lowercase*:

```
object={"locale":"en_US",
object={"locale":"es_ES",
```

and

```
object={"locale":"en_us",
object={"locale":"en_es",
```

when creating the objects via POST.

**b)** I tried

```
&locale=us_US
&locale=es_ES
```

and

```
&locale=us_us
&locale=es_es
```

when fetching the objects via GET.

I also tested the meta version:

```
&og:locale=us_US
&og:locale=es_ES
```

and

```
&og:locale=us_us
&og:locale=es_es
```

without any luck.

**c)** I tried to create the English object before the Spanish object, and vice versa, but only  the last updated object was fetched via GET, whatever the value of the *locale* parameter was.

**d)** I tried to create the objects exactly like you did, and also exactly how it's done in the example.

So I would suggest you to report this to Facebook as a bug or a wrong documentation.

---

**Update:**

Please check out this similar question and it's answer:

[facebook localization of hosted objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545549/facebook-localization-of-hosted-objects)

It looks like it's already been [reported to Facebook and confirmed since January 23rd 2014!](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/697517653622499/).

Would have saved us lot of testing time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never work with custom localized OpenGraph object, but I found the docs

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#selfhosted-creating
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/#propertytypes-standardtypes
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#selfhosted-update
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/internationalization/#objects

The last link states that:

> Object property values can be stored in multiple languages. To make
>   sure your object is scraped in multiple languages, make sure to do
>   either of the following:
>
> - Call the Graph API to update the object URL with the locale parameter.
> - Specify an array of og:locale:alternate meta tags to define which
>     locales you support.

There are some detail down the paragraph as well. Have you tried to use the OpenGraph debugger on your object?

In your output, I saw that is_scraped is false. have you tried to add the parameter **&scrape=true** to your requests like this (as described in the second last link):

```
OBJECTID=$(curl -X POST \
-F 'object={"locale":"es_ES",
            "title":"mi objeto",
            "description":"mi descripción", 
            "data": { "obj_extra":"mi información" } }' \
"https://graph.facebook.com/$APPID/objects/$APPNAMESPACE:$OBJTYPE?scrape=true&access_token=$APPID|$APPSECRET")
```

Comment: note that my question specifies "hosted objects" not "self-hosted objects" therefore meta tags do not apply. the examples in the facebook documentation are simply not working for me. scrape does not help in this case.